# How to enable help mode by default in ed

Tags: ed

After starting `ed`, help mode can be enabled using the `H` command. Is there a way to enable help mode by default, so that I do not have to type `H` every time I use `ed`?

Comment: From reading `man ed`, you cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With standard `ed`, you will have to enter `H` manually at the start of an interactive editing session, or include `H` at the start of any `ed` editing script.

The OpenBSD `ed` manual [suggests this](https://man.openbsd.org/ed#H) for `ed` scripts:

> `H`
> Toggles the printing of error explanations.  By default,
> explanations are not printed.  It is recommended that `ed` scripts
> begin with this command to aid in debugging.

The GNU `ed` implementation has a command line option, `-v` (or `--verbose`), which enables `H` in the editing session.  You may alias `ed` to `ed -v` if you want this to be the default behavior.

> `-v`, `--verbose`
> be verbose; equivalent to the `H` command

Comment: Excellent. For GNU ed, all I need to do is to run `rlwrap ed -vp'*'` to get a comfortable editing session.

Comment: @Flux So, `alias ed="rlwrap ed -v -p '*'"` then.